# I want the highest and the lowest value of a table, why can't I save that value in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-variables

```
$category = htmlspecialchars($_GET['category']);

$sql = "(SELECT number 
        FROM german 
        WHERE german.category_german LIKE ".$category." 
        ORDER BY number DESC 
        LIMIT 1) as 'high', 
        (SELECT number 
        FROM german 
        WHERE german.category_german LIKE ".$category." 
        ORDER BY number ASC 
        LIMIT 1) as 'low'";
    if ($result = $conn -> query($sql)) {
      while ($row = $result -> fetch_row()) {
        
          $high_value = $row[high];
          $low_value = $row[low];
          $r_n = rand($low_value,$high_value).PHP_EOL;
          echo $r_n;
          }

      }
```

What am I missing? I want the highest and the lowest value of a table, why can't I save that value in PHP? I just can't access the values. And I tried out MIN and MAX as well, but they didn't function neither:

```
$category = htmlspecialchars($_GET['category']);

$sql = "SELECT MIN('number') AS 'low', MAX('number') AS 'high' FROM german WHERE german.category_german LIKE ".$category."";
    if ($result = $conn -> query($sql)) {
      while ($row = $result -> fetch_row()) {
          $high_value = $row[high];
          $low_value = $row[low];
          $r_n = rand($low_value,$high_value).PHP_EOL;
          echo $r_n;
          }

      }
```

As a result of $r_n I only get 0. The database shouldn't be the problem. Beforehand (where I only used the highest value) everything functioned:

```
$category = htmlspecialchars($_GET['category']);

$sql = "SELECT number FROM german WHERE german.category_german LIKE ".$category." ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 1";
if ($result = $conn -> query($sql)) {
  while ($row = $result -> fetch_row()) {
    
      $r_n = $row[0];
      $r_n = rand(1,$r_n).PHP_EOL;
      echo $r_n;
      }

  }
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string.

Comment: Because all your attempts have simple but catestrophic coding errors in them

Comment: Start by providing the schema for the table `german`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use multiple `SELECT` statements at top-level of a query. They would have to be subqueries:

```
SELECT (SELECT ...) AS high, (SELECT ...) AS low
```

Your second query would have worked, but you shouldn't have quotes around `number`. That makes it a literal string, not the column values. So `MAX('number')` should be `MAX(number)`, `MIN('number')` should be `MIN(number)`. See [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

And if `category` is a string, you need to put quotes around `$category`:

```
WHERE german.category_german LIKE '".$category."'"
```

But the better way to resolve that problem is to use a prepared statement with parameters, [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-phprather) than substituting variables directly into the query. See

Comment: I changed the code to: $category = htmlspecialchars($_GET['category']);
$sql = "SELECT MIN(number) AS 'low', MAX(number) AS 'high' FROM german WHERE german.category_german LIKE '".$category."'";
if ($result = $conn -> query($sql)) {
  while ($row = $result -> fetch_row()) {
      
      $high_value = $row[high];
      $low_value = $row[low];
      $r_n = rand($low_value,$high_value).PHP_EOL;
      echo "<p>".$r_n."</p>"; But it still doesn't work on the website (on phpmyadmin it works)

Comment: There's no need for a `while` loop since it always returns exactly 1 row.

Comment: If it's not returning anything you should display the error message. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-in-different-environments

Comment: Please, again basic coding error! Arrays are addressed as `$row['low']` not `$row[low]`

Comment: @RiggsFolly True, although it will work with the warning that the undefined constant is being treated as a string literal.

Comment: For reference, in PHP 8 that now becomes a `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "low"`